# Jenkins Pipeline - conditional execution with branch and 1 other parameter (manual)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

We are deploying our application using Jenkins pipeline like this -

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Build For Production') {
        when { branch 'development' }
        steps {
             sh './bin/build.sh'
        }
    }
    stage('Build For Production') {
        when { branch 'master' }
        steps {
             sh './bin/copy_needed_auth.sh'
             sh './bin/build.sh'
        }
    }
  }
}
```

When a developer pushes code on bitbucket, The application is deployed automatically. Using branch, we set our deployment strategy.

```
when { branch 'master' }
```

But we need to set a manual chacking for deploying on production (master branch) like - when a developer will merge code in the master branch, he will also set some tag or something like that so that Jenkins pipeline will check branch + other manual logic to deploy in production.

we are doing like this -

```
when { 
    branch 'master' 
    tag: 'release-*'
}
```

But it's not working. Is there any other strategy to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to use several `when` conditions:

```
when { 
  allOf { 
    branch 'master'; 
    tag "release-*"
  }
}
```

Related docs you can find [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)

Comment: It's not working, Jenkins file output - Stage "Build For Production" skipped due to when conditional

Comment: because condition will work only when branch = master and you set tag to release-*. If you need to meet not all but at least one condition, when use 'anyof' instead 'allof'